# Dynamic allocation of memory in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I need to store five names of songs in memory using dynamic allocation and then print them to the screen.

What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXIM 5

void main() {
    char song[30];
    char *p;

    p = (char*)calloc(MAXIM, sizeof(song) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIM; i++) {
        printf("Name of the song %d:\n", i);
        scanf("%s", song);
        strcpy(p[i], song);
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIM; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", p[i]);
        free(p[i]);
    }

     getch();
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: The variable `p` is not an array of strings. It's a pointer to `char` so it can be *a* string, but not an array of strings. You seem to want an array of arrays of `char` (like `char p[MAXIM][30]`). Start with that and think about how to dynamically allocate the different parts.

Comment: type of `p[i]` is `char`.

Comment: `void main(){}` =>> `int main(void){}`

Comment: @SouravGhosh he used C++ as C (see visual-studio tag and `for (int i = 0;`)

Comment: http://ideone.com/cDfG3B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes that are corrected and explained in the following code. Besides, `scanf()` is replaced by `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXIM 5
#define NAME_SIZE 30

int main(void) {
    char *p[MAXIM];  /* MAXIM pointers to char */

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIM; i++) {
        p[i] = calloc(1, NAME_SIZE + 1);
        printf("Name of the song %d:\n", i);
        /* reads a maximum of NAME_SIZE chars including trailing newline */
        fgets(p[i], NAME_SIZE+1, stdin);   
        /* removes trailing newline */
        p[i][strcspn(p[i], "\r\n")] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIM; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);  /* %s format specifier */
        free(p[i]);
    }
    getch();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Potential buffer overflow in `scanf("%s", p[i])`

Comment: @chqrlie You're right. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate a 2D array of `char` but use a simple pointer to `char` to access it.  Use the proper pointer type: pointer to an array of arrays of 30 `char`, namely `char (*p)[30];` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXIM 5

int main(void) {
    char song[30];
    char (*p)[30];
    int n;

    p = calloc(MAXIM, sizeof(*p));
    for (n = 0; n < MAXIM; n++) {
        printf("Name of the song %d:\n", n);
        if (fgets(p[n], sizeof(p[n]), stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        p[n][strcspn(p[n], "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the trailing newline
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
    }
    free(p);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `scanf()` should be given the maximum number of characters to read into the destination array.
- `free()` the allocated pointer, not individual subarrays.
- `main()` returns an `int`.

Comment: It does not work if the name of a song contains a white space since `sscanf("%29s", p[i])` stops at a whitespace.

Comment: @chus: that's true.  The OP's code has this shortcoming too. Your solution handles this correctly.  I shall update my code.